Generalizations of the Minimal Polynomial
This is an open-ended question. Thank you very much for taking the time to read it and investing any time to answer it.
Given a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space $V$ and a linear map $T:V\to V$, there is a unique monic polynomial $\mu _{T}\in k[x]$ of smallest degree satisfying $$\mu _{T}(T)=0.$$Furthermore, that $k[x]$ is a PID tells us that for any $p\in k[x]$ that annihilates $T$, we have $\mu _{T}\mid p$.
My question is: are there generalizations?
I am aware of the Generalized Cayley-Hamilton Theorem that works for any finitely-generated (f.g. for brevity) module over any commutative ring. However, in the finite-dimensional vector space case, the characteristic polynomial is a multiple of the minimal polynomial.
Is there a notion of the minimal polynomial for f.g. module endomorphisms? If not for f.g. modules over general commutative rings, what about f.g. modules over a PID? Any integral domain? A Noetherian ring?
Alternatively, what if the module is free? Projective?

A totally different direction in which to generalize is to consider multiple maps: see parts of my video here on mixed Cayley-Hamilton for example.

For every element $a \in A$ of an algebra $A$ over a commutative ring $R$ we can consider the ideal $I(a) := \{f \in R[T] : f(a)=0\}$. It is the kernel of the unique algebra homomorphism $R[T] \to A$ mapping $T \mapsto a$.
The usual definition of a minimal polynomial of $a$ is to define it to be some generator of $I(a)$ when $I(a)$ is a principal ideal. And when there is a canonical choice to ensure uniqueness, we do that as well. If $I(a)$ isn't principal, there is no minimal polynomial.
For $A = \mathrm{End}(V)$ and $R$ a field we get the notion used in linear algebra. Here the minimal polynomial always exists since $R[T]$ is a PID. It is either non-zero, which corresponds to the usual case, but it can also be zero, which means the endomorphism doesn't satisfy any algebraic relation. For example, the left shift on the vector space of infinite sequences has minimal polynomial $0$. The endomorphism $x \mapsto -x$ on this infinite-dimensional vector space has minimal polynomial $T^2-1$.
In field theory, not just $R$ but also $A$ is a field. Here one speaks of the minimal polynomial of an element. But as you see these notions are the same.
But in general the minimal polynomial (as defined above) will not exist, even when $A=\mathrm{End}(R^n)=M_n(R)$. Consider $a=\begin{pmatrix} u & 0 \\ 0 & v \end{pmatrix}$. Then $I(a)=\{f \in R[T] : f(u)=f(v)=0\} = (T-u) \cap (T-v)$ is not necessarily principal, namely when $v-u$ is a non-zero zero divisor.
Maybe there are other definitions, but I am not aware of them.
